# Remove Quoting at start and end of fields in a CSV document

Tags: java, regex, string, csv

I'm receiving some CSV documents but some of them have every single field inside quotations **`"`** like this example row:

```
|ROW 01| ->  "0001" ; "NULL" ; "Value" ; "Random comment with "quotations" inside"
```

So i want to remove the surrounding quoting, but not the ones inside text, the problem is that i often receive files with rows like, for example :

```
|ROW 02| -> ;;;
|ROW 03| -> (empty line)
|ROW 04| -> ;NULL";;"SomeText     <-     (Opening or Closing quotes but not paired)
```

In the end, i think i only need to remove **`"`** if :

- **`"`** At Start of line/String (Since im reading the files line by line)
- **`"`** At end of String
- **`";`**
- **`;"`**

I found myself inside a terrible mix of splits, replaces and regex so i'm looking for new ideas

Comment: Write your own parser.

Comment: You can create custom logic to read your csv file as text and perform clean the data recoding a new cleaned file as output.

Comment: @Toto I thought about it but i do not know enough about file formats, encoding and casuistry that i would need to check so i was hoping to make do with a regex that took care of those 4 particular cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working for my particular needs by using this RegEx and removing the matches / replacing them with `""`

```regex
    ^ *\"|(?<=\;) *\"|\" *$|\" *(?=;)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yRkj1KNMj-57UONh)

Comment: I don’t think that all these brackets make the regex more readable. The nesting has no effect. Compare with a plain regex like `^ *\"|(?<=\;) *\"|\" *$|\" *(?=;)`

Comment: @holger You're right, i just wrote them at first to make it easier to write in the first place and see them in the diagram and then left it as is, will edit the answer though, thank you for pointing it out!